# No some prompt styles in configuration wizard Powerlevel10k

Tags: terminal, themes, oh-my-zsh

I use ubuntu 22.04. When i try to configure p10k, there is no some promt styles.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVeAJ.png)

I installed MesloLGS NF font, also i tried to reinstall p10k, nothing helped. Also i have utf-8.
.zshrc:

```
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme
```

Comment: Did you verify that p10k.zsh has been sourced? Aside from this, I think your question is better asked at [su].

Comment: _Also i have utf-8_ : What does it mean, to **have** UTF8?